# GridView to Excel using EPPlus

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to create an excel sheet using the EPPlus's library.
However, the output excel file does not relate well to cells of representing numbers.

[image]

The code I'm using is:

```
using (var pck = new ExcelPackage())
{
    ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(string.IsNullOrEmpty(SpreadsheetName) ? "Report" : SpreadsheetName);
    ws.Cells["B2"].LoadFromDataTable(gridViewTable, true, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Light1);

    for (int i = 1; i <= gridViewTable.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        ws.Column(i).AutoFit();
    }

    // **************
    //     HEADER
    // **************

    //prepare the range for the column headers
    string cellRange = "B2:" + Convert.ToChar('B' + gridViewTable.Columns.Count - 1) + 2;

    //Format the header for columns
    using (ExcelRange rng = ws.Cells[cellRange])
    {
        rng.Style.WrapText = false;
        rng.Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
        rng.Style.Font.Bold = true;
        rng.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid; //Set Pattern for the background to Solid
        rng.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#007A99"));
        rng.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.White);
    }

    // ************
    //     DATA
    // ************

    //prepare the range for the rows
    string rowsCellRange = "B3:" + Convert.ToChar('B' + gridViewTable.Columns.Count - 1) + (gridViewTable.Rows.Count + 1);

    //Format the rows
    using (ExcelRange rng = ws.Cells[rowsCellRange])
    {
        rng.Style.WrapText = false;
        rng.Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Left;
        rng.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid; //Set Pattern for the background to Solid
        rng.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#B2D1F0"));
        rng.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.Black);
    }

    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FileName) ? "Report" : FileName) + ".xlsx");
    Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
}
```

Does anyone might know why is this happening ?

Comment: What's the type of the affected column in the source `DataTable`?

Comment: I'm converting the GridView to a DataTable object. The former holds template fields with Labels. The data is represented within the Text properties. However, I'm still converting these Labels' Text properties to Double types and then creating the relevant row for the DataTable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

If you use the LoadFromDataTable() method, the DataTable object should be typed in its columns, meaning that you should create the columns using 
table.Columns.Add(columnName, columnType);